# There is very clear prior art for patent application WO2014145999A

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant

In reference to the patent: [WO2014145999A3](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2014145999A3)

The inventions in this patent are entirely described by the Diploma Thesis of Kai Niklas submitted on 11th June 2010
http://www.l3s.de/~tahmasebi/Diplomarbeit_Niklas.pdf

The priority date on this patent is Mar 15, 2013, years after the publication of Kai Niklas' thesis.

This thesis described in detail the OCR Key algorithm as described in this patent, including the same steps of the claim executed in the same order.

The thesis even described the algorithm using the same name, the "OCR Key" algorithm.

There is no reference the the thesis of Kai Niklas in this patent application, whereas it clearly should have been cited as prior art.

There is no novel content in this patent and the application should be rejected.

Comment: Do you have any prove that the thesis was published prior to the application dates?

Comment: so what is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

The international search has found prior art for all three claims. Claim 1 and 3 were deemed not new and claim 2 obvious. https://register.epo.org/ipfwretrieve?apn=US.2014030867.W&lng=en

Since then, no action has been taken by the applicant.

The entry into the national phase has to be done max. 30/31 months after the filing of the PCT application - this has passed.

Therefore, this patent is not getting granted anywhere, it has lapsed.